# Wordpress NGINX redirect everything to new domain EXCEPT

Tags: wordpress, nginx

I have an unusual setup in that I have an angularJS application running on `http://example.com` which pulls data via the wordpress api located at `http://api.example.com`.

`http://api.example.com` needs to have the `/wp-login`, `/wp-admin`, `/wp-content`, and `/wp-includes` urls to work as if it is still a regular wordpress site.

However all other url's like `http://api.example.com/category/excategory` or `http://api.example.com/this-is-a-post-title` need to redirect 301 to the `http://example.com domain.`

example:

```
http://api.example.com/category/excategory
```

redirects to

```
http://example.com/category/excategory
```

but

```
http://api.example.com/wp-admin (and anything after it)
```

does not.

I've tried all kinds of crazy things, but my location blocks seem to either conflict, or I get weird url's that go to nowhere.

Here's a try that failed:

```
location ~ /wp-(?:admin|login|includes|content) {
index index.php;
try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
}

location / {
   return 301 $scheme//example.com$request_uri
}
```

Comment: Try to update your permalink structure. See if your .htaccess file is writable or not.

Comment: considering this is a NGINX setup, would .htaccess be an appropriate solution?

Comment: Hmm, .htaccess is not an appropriate solution for that. Try to put permalink structure to default and see you can access the pages.

Comment: I can access the pages, except I want them to redirect to a new domain except for the ones I mentioned above. It's not a matter of no access, I'm just trying to figure out a redirect rule for SOME of the pages.

Answer (score 1):

Put this code in your WP Theme Functions.php file. It should redirect all urls except the one who contain wp-admin:

```
 add_action('init','_redirect_api_url');

 function _redirect_api_url(){
    $redirect = TRUE;
    $pathNotToRedirect = array('wp-admin','wp-content', 'wp-login','wp-includes');
    $path = "http://example.com".$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
    foreach($pathNotToRedirect as $val){
        if(strpos($path, $val)){
           $redirect = FALSE;
           break;  
        }
    }
    if($redirect == TRUE) {
       header("Location: ".$path);

    }
 }
```

Comment: Will this also redirect /wp-content /wp-login and /wp-includes? I need those to stay at api.example.com